# How to use a global javascript variable inside css?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an asp.net mvc application. I need to know how to use global javascript variables inside html code. I know global variables are not an ideal solution to a problem but for my solution to work I need them.

I know about their declaration. Here is an example of how I want to use them. I want to use the global js variable to be already filled in at the input.

```js
var title;
function foo(b) {
  title = b;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value=title readonly>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to set the value of `title` into the input's attribute `value`? if so, you didn't call that function as well as you're only setting a string "title" to the attribute value.

Comment: _for my solution to work I need them_ - then your solution is wrong.

Comment: You need to put an identifier for your field, e.g. ```id="my-input"```. Then from the JavaScript global scope you may use ```document.getElementById('my-input').value = title;```

Comment: @chrispbacon Don't be so arrogant. This might not be an XY problem. The OP asks about using a JS value in CSS, not whether global variables are evil.

Comment: Why does the title talk about CSS when there is no CSS in the question? I assume an edit has been made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var title;

function foo(b) {
  document.getElementById("title").value = b;
};

foo("irin")
```

```html
<input type="text" id="title" readonly>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `setProperty` function of the `style` object of any `HTMLElement` object

```js
"use strict";

// Note the double quotation '" and "'
// I won't work without, if you want to use the value
// with CSS content rule
const title = '"My title"';
document.getElementById('title').style.setProperty('--title', title);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

div:before {
  content: var(--title, 'not set');
}
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>
```

In the above example I used a `[CSS custom Property][1]`, but you could do without

```js
"use strict";

const title = '"My title"';

const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = `#title:before {
  content: ${title};
}`;
document.head.append(style);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="title"></div>
```

Comment: @chrispbacon You are right. I overread this. I only read the title which involves CSS. Then I started coding. But I'll leave this for other people to maybe be of use.